Unable to see center text and subtext in Chart.js doughnut chart
I am using Chart.js for a doughnut chart in a React application. I have used this component twice, but I am unable to see the center text and subtext. I am also having trouble registering the plugin.
import React from 'react';
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { ChartData, ChartOptions, Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { NUMBER_FIFTEEN, NUMBER_ZERO } from 'utils/GeneralConstants';
import './style.scss';

interface MyChartOptions extends ChartOptions {
    cutout?: any;
    responsive?: boolean;
    maintainAspectRatio?: boolean;
    plugins?: any;
    scales?: any;
    spacing?: number;
}

interface ChartDetails {
    activeCount?: number;
    deactiveCount?: number;
    otherStatuses?: number;
    connected?: number;
    disconnected?: number;
}

interface DoughnutChartProps {
    chartDetails: ChartDetails;
    CenterText: string;
    subText: string;
    backgroundColor: string[];
    borderColor: string[];
    labels: string[];
    chartLabels: string[];
}

const DoughnutChart: React.FC<DoughnutChartProps> = (props: DoughnutChartProps) => {
    const { chartDetails, CenterText, subText, backgroundColor, borderColor, chartLabels } = props;
    const chartDetailsArray = Object.values(chartDetails);

    console.log('chartDetailsArray', chartDetailsArray);
    console.log('props', props);



    const data: ChartData<'doughnut'> = {
        labels: chartLabels,
        datasets: [
            {
                data: chartDetailsArray,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                borderColor: borderColor,
                borderWidth: [0],
            },
        ],
    };

    

    const options: MyChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        cutout: '85%',
        spacing: 8,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            doughnutLabel: {
                id: 'doughnutLabel',
                afterUpdate: (chart: any) => {
                    const { ctx, config } = chart;
                    const centerX = (chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2;
                    const centerY = (chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2;

                    ctx.save();
                    ctx.font = 'bold 32px  sans-serif';
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                    ctx.fillText(CenterText, centerX, centerY - 10);
                    ctx.font = '16px  sans-serif';
                    ctx.fillText(subText, centerX, centerY + 25);
                    ctx.restore();
                },
            },
        },
    };
    // Chart.register(centerTextPlugin);

    return (
        <div className="doughnut-chart">
            <Doughnut aria-label="Doughnut chart" data={data} options={options} height={180} width={180} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default DoughnutChart;

I am using Chart.js for doughnut chart i have have used this component twice but not able to see the center text and subtext and unable to register the plugin
I want to see the center text and subtext which i pass through the components

You are mixing up plugin definitions with plugin options. Your plugins.legend sets the options for the legend plugin and is rightly placed there. doughnutLabel is the definition of your custom plugin and is misplaced in MyChartOptions. It belongs to a plugins array, at the top level of the configuration. Thus, you may define the plugin object separately, as const doughnutLabel = {id:...., afterUpdate: ....}; and add it to the top level of your chart as  <Doughnut data={data} options={options} plugins={[doughnutLabel]} ...; this way, you don't need to register the plugin.
